# Hash content doesn't change

Tags: perl, hash, size

Why doesn't the content of my hash `hh`change? How can I keep the changes in the main part after calling `func`?

```
my @RR = (1,2);
foreach(@RR)
{
    my %hh;
    &func(\%hh);
    print "SIZE: ".keys(%hh)."\n";
}

sub func
{
    my %hh = %{$_[0]};
    my $n="noob";
    my $m="moon";
    $hh{$n}{$m}[0]="hey";
    $hh{$n}{$m}[1]="bye";
}
```

output:

```
SIZE: 0
SIZE: 0
```

Comment: You are creating a new lexical variable `%hh` for each iteration of your for loop.

Comment: I know but even in each iteration, after calling `func`, `%hh` still remains empty.

Comment: You create a new instance of `%hh` inside your sub. It shadows the previous instance of `%hh` from your loop. You are passing a reference, but dereferencing it and creating a copy in your sub.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating new copies of `%hh` for each loop iteration, and each sub usage. You pass your argument by reference, but that does not matter, since you copy the values anyway inside the sub. This:

```
my %foo = %$bar;
```

..makes a copy of `$bar`, and any changes to `%foo` is not passed on to `$bar`.

Here is a commented version of your script:

```
foreach(@RR)
{
    my %hh;                      # new variable %hh created each loop iteration
    &func(\%hh);                 # hash passed by reference
    print "SIZE: ".keys(%hh)."\n";
}

sub func
{
    my %hh = %{$_[0]};           # new variable %hh created, key/values copied
    my $n="noob";
    my $m="moon";
    $hh{$n}{$m}[0]="hey";        # copy of %hh affected
    $hh{$n}{$m}[1]="bye";
}                                # copy of %hh goes out of scope, values lost
```

If you wanted this to work as expected, you would need to use the real reference:

```
sub func {
    my $ref = shift;
    $ref->{"noob"}{"moon"}[0] = "hey";
    $ref->{"noob"}{"moon"}[1] = "bye";
}
```

Comment: then do `my ($arg1, $arg2, $hhref, $arg4, $arg5) = @_`

Comment: @user3991583 That is irrelevant. Using `shift` is just one way of accessing `@_`. Not sure why you think that using `shift` is not possible while using many args.

Comment: I'm not saying it's impossible. Let's put it this way: Would `$ref = %{$_[0]}` also work?

Comment: @user3991583 You could do `my $ref = $_[0]`, but the only difference from using `shift` is that you would not alter `@_`. You seem to be confused about how `shift` works. If you would like, I can explain to you why using `shift` is perfectly fine.

Comment: @TLP You actually already did by saying not altering `@_`. Thanks.

Comment: @user3991583 You're welcome. You should know, even though you don't want to hear it, that most often, using a direct reference is undesirable, since it leads to altering the original value. This does of course not apply when the value is a reference.